# $T: H^{-\infty}(R^n) \to H^\infty(R^n)$ continuous iff $T: H^{-r}(R^n) \to H^s(R^n)$ bounded for all $r,s>0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Denote by $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the Sobolev space on $\mathbb{R}^n$ of order $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and recall that we have $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)^\ast \cong H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for the dual space of $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Furthermore, let
$$H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n) := \bigcap_{s \in \mathbb{N}} H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
equipped with the natural Frechet topology, and let
$$H^{-\infty}(R^n) := \bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{N}} H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
equipped with the weak-$^\ast$-topology that it gets as the dual of $H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

A continuous operator $T\colon H^{-\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is called a smoothing operator. Since both $H^{-\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are locally convex spaces, this means that for all $s \in \mathbb{N}$ there are finitely many functions $f_1, \ldots, f_{N_s} \in H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and an $M_s > 0$ such that
$$\|T \varphi\|_{H^s} \le M_s \cdot \max_{1 \le j \le N_s} \varphi(f_j)$$
for all $\varphi \in H^{-\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

From this we can conclude that $T$ is a bounded operator $H^{-r}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $r,s \in \mathbb{N}$.

> Does the converse hold, i.e., if $T\colon H^{-r}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is bounded for all $r,s \in \mathbb{N}$, does $T$ define a continuous operator $H^{-\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let me partially answer my own question.

If we equip $H^{-\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the inductive limit topology, then by definition of the topologies an operator $T \colon H^{-\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is continuous if and only if it is continuous as an operator $H^{-r}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Since each $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a Hilbert space, the Frechet space $H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the projective limit of reflexive Banach spaces, and therefore $H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is totally reflexive. We conclude that $H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is distinguished and one characterization of being distinguished is that on its dual space $H^{-\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the strong topology and the inductive limit topology coincide.

Now the strong topology and the weak-$^\ast$-topology on a dual space are in general quite different and therefore the **answer to my above question is probably "not necessarily"**.